# Is setlocale restricted to its script instance?

Tags: php, apache, session, locale

According to PHP, "locale information is maintained per process." Is my understanding correct that this is the same as saying per script instance with an Apache server?

In other words, if I have several concurrent sessions using different locales, can changes in one user's locale settings interfere with another's?

Also is there a conventional stateful way to set locale information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Setting a different locale will not affect another user's settings. It's per script (dynamic) and isn't save anywhere.